# Get video's privacy settings using Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

In YouTube video manager, I have the option to set a video to a) Public b) Private and c) Unlisted.

Using the YouTube API, is it possible to find out what the setting of a video is currently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends.

I'm going to answer in the context of the [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), which is the most recent release. There are analogous methods in the older v1 and v2 of the API.

If you're [authenticated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) as the owner of the video, you can make a [`videos.list(part=status, id=VIDEO_ID)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call, and the video's status will be returned in the [`video.status.privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) property.

If you're not authenticated as the owner of the video, you can make the same `videos.list()` call, but if the video is `private` you won't get back a response. If the video is `public` or `unlisted` you will get back a video resource, and you could check `video.status.privacyStatus` to see what the exact privacy level is.

```
google_api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
video_ids = 'VIDEO_ID_1,VIDEO_ID_2'

# Construct the API URL to retrieve video statuses for multiple videos
video_url = f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video_ids}&part=status&key={google_api_key}'
```

Comment: Hi, I know i'm gravedigging about this right now, but why are unlisted videos accessible through the API ? I mean: is this WAI or a Bug ?

Answer (score 3):

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=giOAHm-dRaM&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Use the link above to get the privacy settings of a video