# youtube allow specific user from my web app to view my youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am making a web app where user can view video. That video I will upload in youtube. When the user is registered in my web app, he can then view the video I have uploaded or the video in my channel.

Is it possible to do this?? I want to upload videos in my youtube channel and allow only the user from my web app to view the video.

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Here are the concepts of using OAuth.

- When a user first attempts to use functionality in your application that requires the user to be logged in to a Google Account or YouTube account, your application initiates the OAuth 2.0 authorization process.
- Your application directs the user to Google's authorization server. The link to that page specifies the `scope` of access that your application is requesting for the user's account. The `scope` specifies the resources that your application can retrieve, insert, update, or delete when acting as the authenticated user.
- If the user consents to authorize your application to access those resources, Google returns a token to your application. Depending on your application's type, it either validates the token or exchanges it for a different type of token.

If it is just a simple video, then you can try to set the privacy settings of your video. You can either set it as `public`, `unlisted` and `private`. It will return in the [`status.privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus).

If you want to know on how to set it in your code, you can follow this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video#Sample_Code).

For more information, you can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341531/get-videos-privacy-settings-using-youtube-api).

Comment: I can make user login from google. I only want to show the video in my site. User that are not loogged into my system should not be able to view the video in youtube directly...